# TeamCity WCF RIA lack of assemblies during build

Tags: .net, teamcity, wcf-ria-services, .net-assembly

I can’t make Teamcity to build my WCF RIA + Silverlight 5 app. Problem is lack of assemblies included in build command (csc.exe). Parameters to csc.exe command does not include required assemblies:

```
Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.dll
Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Tools.dll
System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.EntityFramework.dll
System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.dll
System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.OData.dll
System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.dll
```

Every other assembly is included properly. In .csproj file mentioned assemblies are listed properly. Files are present in system in proper directories.

Can anyone tell me how to make TeamCity to include those files?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not a specific TeamCity issue but a CI issue. When you push / commit or what ever you Source Control supports the changes are picked up by your CI server. It then pulls the latest code and tries to compile it. If your source control does not contain all the right assemblies and it cannot find those assemblies either by getting from NuGet or by looking in the GAC the code will fail to compile.

To resolve this you can do one of three things.

1. Identify the assemblies you need, find them on your local development machine, add them to your source controls lib folder and change the solution projects to reference the assemblies from there.
2. If you are using NuGet see if the assemblies that you want are available from Nuget (try here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/RIAServices.Server/)
3. Install the missing assemblies into the GAC on your CI server (and build agents)

If you don't use NuGet then 1 is the best option. 3 is the worst option because your CI server is now dirty. The more you install on your CI the dirtier it becomes. The point here is that if you have components on your CI server that allow your build to compile you will not know that there is probably going to be missing components when you attempt to release your product onto a live server.